# malformed JSON Error in Sqlite when i use json_extract funciton

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, json-query, json-extract

In my sqllite table i have field named `config` which stores configuration in the form of json text..

bellow is the sample data stored in `config` field

```
{
"matRid": 1,
"holderType": 1,
"uomRid": 1,
"type": 502,
"stockConditionIndex": 800,
"serialRequired": 1,
"codepart": 1,
"allowEdit": 1
}
```

from this data when I run the bellow query it throws  `malformed JSON` error

```
 select json_extract(config, '$.codepart') as codepart FROM TableName
```

to test whether json is in the correct format or not i have run the following query

```
select json_valid(config) from TableName
```

above query retuns 1, this confirms that json is in the proper format

and also if I run the query by directly like bellow, using the json value of the field `config` query will return result successfully,

```
select json_extract('{
"matRid": 1,
"holderType": 1,
"uomRid": 1,
"type": 502,
"stockConditionIndex": 800,
"serialRequired": 1,
"codepart": 1,
"allowEdit": 1
}', '$.codepart') as codepart FROM TableName
```

How to make `json_extract` work by using the column name instead of json value direclty in SqlLite?

additional info : SQLite Version 3.35.5.

any suggestions would be helpfull.. Thank you..

Comment: But it worked at sqlffidle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCsKGkz7zzEQ3E3NEqbTfg/0 could you check your json data from your data base?

Comment: @D-Shih in the Table some of the field's for column `config` had `NULL` or `EMPTY` data; the Error was Produced by `json_extract` for the Row with `EMPTY` data (empty string).. resolved it By including a `IIF statement` to check empty field in query.. Thank You for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was actually produced by the `json_extract` for the rows with empty record (empty string) for the field `config`

resolved it by including the IIF statement

```
SELECT json_extract(json(IIF(config <> '', config, NULL)), '$.codepart') from TableName
```